# IOS HockeyApp Crash Log | The application did not terminate cleanly but no crash occured

Tags: ios, logging, crash

I am getting lots of crash logs on HockeyApp and it just says "The application did not terminate cleanly but no crash occured". Is it something to do with the background tasks?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen when you have HockeyApp's [AppNotTerminatingCleanlyDetection](https://www.hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/4.1.5/Classes/BITCrashManager.html#//api/name/enableAppNotTerminatingCleanlyDetection) enabled. This is a heuristic that enables you to track crashes or kills of an iOS application while it is in the foreground that would otherwise not be detectable by an app's in-process crash reporter:

> This allows it to get a crash report if the app got killed while being in the foreground because of one of the following reasons:
>
> - The main thread was blocked for too long
> - The app took too long to start up
> - The app tried to allocate too much memory. If iOS did send a memory warning before killing the app because of this reason, `didReceiveMemoryWarningInLastSession` returns `YES`.
> - Permitted background duration if main thread is running in an endless loop
> - App failed to resume in time if main thread is running in an endless loop
> - If `enableMachExceptionHandler` is not activated, crashed due to stack overflow will also be reported
>
> The following kills can NOT be detected:
>
> - Terminating the app takes too long
> - Permitted background duration too long for all other cases
> - App failed to resume in time for all other cases
>   possibly more cases
> - Crash reports triggered by this mechanisms do NOT contain a

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Is there anyway to get more details of the crash? I have never faced any random crashes during testing. Thanks,

Comment: The only way is to leverage the data of iOS's built-in crash reporter, either by having access directly to one of the devices affected or by hoping the crash reports eventually also show up in iTunes Connect.

Comment: @Bilal I am having a tremendously difficult time with this same issue. Can you please tell me how you tracked down the source of your mystery ‘crashes’?